# Foreach loop bugs (maybe) in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code where I want to show all `news` in blade file, I have around 30+ data in database, but it shows only 1 news in blade, I can't understand why it is like this. The same process is used for to get `notifications` and everything works...xD

My Controller

```
public function getNews() {
    $news = News::orderBy('date', 'DESC')->paginate();
    return view('information.news', [
        'news' => $news
    ]);
}
```

News.blade.php

```
@if (count($news) > 0)
  <div class="row">
   @foreach($news as $n)
    {{ $n->title }}
   @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    {{ $news->links() }}
  </div>
@else
  <p>No News</p>
@endif
```

I try copy pase the `notification` page and changes variable to `news` but only 1 data again..

When I `dd($news);` it gives 38 when I use `get()`

When I `{{ count($news) }}` it gives 38 when I use `get()`

But only 1 data is display in loop

Comment: Have you tried outputting the `id` instead of the title? `#{{ $n->id }}` There might be HTML issues with one of the titles

Comment: @kerbh0lz yeah this maybe the problem, id gives me 15 data.. let me recheck the html

Answer (score 0):

When you **paginate()**, your result is stored in a **array where data is the key**.

e.g.

```
{
   "total": 50,
   "per_page": 15,
   "current_page": 1,
   "last_page": 4,
   "first_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=1",
   "last_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=4",
   "next_page_url": "http://laravel.app?page=2",
   "prev_page_url": null,
   "path": "http://laravel.app",
   "from": 1,
   "to": 15,
   "data":[
        {
            // Result Object
        },
        {
            // Result Object
        }
   ]
}
```

In your blade, use it like this:

```
@foreach($news['data'] as $n)
    {{ $n->title }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks, the problem cames because I used `WYSIWYG`.. now I edit the data and everything work fine.. It's not about `paginate`